# How to create start & stop times when multiple start times are given?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to quantify active vs. idle times, and the first thing I need to do is to create distinct and discrete start and end times.  The issue is that the database is (I'm told this is a bug) creating multiple "start" times for the events. To make it even more complicated, a "report" can have multiple instances of being worked on, and each one should be logged as a discrete duration.

For instance,

```
WorkflowID ReportID User Action Timestamp      
1           1         A  Start   1:00      
2           1         A  Stop    1:03      
3           1         B  Start   1:05      
4           1         B  Start   1:06      
5           1         B  Stop    1:08      
6           1         B  Start   1:10      
7           1         B  Start   1:11      
8           1         B  Stop    1:14
```

I want to write a SQL query that would output the following:

```
User StartTime EndTime
A     1:00      1:03
B     1:05      1:08
B     1:10      1:14
```

The issue I'm running into is that the number of start/stop events needs to be arbitrary (per ReportID per User).  In addition, the superfluous "start" times between the first "start" in the series and the following "stop" need to be removed to not mess it up.

Maybe I'm missing something, but this is tricky to me.  Any thoughts?  Thank you.

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you're using as that may make a difference here.

Comment: done, thank you.  your standard ms-sql, using ssms 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deduplicate use `lag()` to compare the previous action for a user and a report with the current one. If they are the same it's a duplicate, mark it as such. Then number the starts and stops using `row_number()`, so that each pair of a start and a stop belonging together share a number (per report and user). Then join on the report, the user and that number.

For convenience you can use CTEs to structure the query and prevent the necessity of duplicating some subqueries.

```
WITH
[DeduplicatedAndNumbered]
AS
(
SELECT [WorkflowID],
       [ReportID],
       [User],
       [Action],
       [Timestamp],
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [ReportID],
                                       [User],
                                       [Action]
                          ORDER BY [Timestamp]) [Number]
       FROM (SELECT [WorkflowID],
                    [ReportID],
                    [User],
                    [Action],
                    [Timestamp],
                    CASE
                      WHEN lag([Action]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ReportId],
                                                            [User]
                                               ORDER BY [Timestamp]) = [Action] THEN
                        1
                      ELSE
                        0
                   END [IsDuplicate]
                   FROM [elbaT]) [x]
       WHERE [IsDuplicate] = 0
),
[DeduplicatedAndNumberedStart]
AS
(SELECT [WorkflowID],
        [ReportID],
        [User],
        [Action],
        [Timestamp],
        [Number]
        FROM [DeduplicatedAndNumbered]
        WHERE [Action] = 'Start'),
[DeduplicatedAndNumberedStop]
AS
(SELECT [WorkflowID],
        [ReportID],
        [User],
        [Action],
        [Timestamp],
        [Number]
        FROM [DeduplicatedAndNumbered]
        WHERE [Action] = 'Stop')
SELECT [DeduplicatedAndNumberedStart].[User],
       [DeduplicatedAndNumberedStart].[Timestamp] [StartTime],
       [DeduplicatedAndNumberedStop].[Timestamp] [EndTime]
       FROM [DeduplicatedAndNumberedStart]
            INNER JOIN [DeduplicatedAndNumberedStop]
                       ON [DeduplicatedAndNumberedStart].[ReportId] = [DeduplicatedAndNumberedStop].[ReportId]
                          AND [DeduplicatedAndNumberedStart].[User] = [DeduplicatedAndNumberedStop].[User]
                          AND [DeduplicatedAndNumberedStart].[Number] = [DeduplicatedAndNumberedStop].[Number];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5cccfbe0a1a26a027028e3aaa16aafac)

Comment: Dedupe using lag() and assigning the row_numbers PER start and stop (I was stuck on keeping them sequential), genius!

Comment: OP added the `sql-server-2008` tag to their question - SSMS 2014 is only the connecting client. Doesn't `lag()` require SQL Server 2012 or later?

Comment: Hope I didn't specify incorrectly.  Luckily, our server did accommodate the lag() function

Answer (score 1):

OP has tagged their question with `sql-server-2008`.

Since SQL Server 2008 lacks the `lag()` function (it was added in [SQL Server 2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/hh231256%28v%3dsql.110%29)), here is a solution that uses [Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms175972%28v%3dsql.90%29) and [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms186734(v=sql.90)) which were available from SQL Server 2005 onwards...

```sql
;with [StopEvents] as (
    select  [WorkflowID],
        [ReportID],
        [User],
        [EndTime] = [Timestamp],
        [StopEventSeq] = row_number() over (
            partition by [ReportID], [User], [Timestamp]
            order by [Timestamp])
    from Workflow
    where [Action] = 'Stop'
)
select  this.[User], [StartTime], this.[EndTime]
from [StopEvents] this
-- Left join here because first Stop event won't have a previous Stop event
left join [StopEvents] previous
    on previous.[ReportID] = this.[ReportID]
    and previous.[User] = this.[User]
    and previous.[StopEventSeq] = this.[StopEventSeq] - 1
outer apply (
    select  [StartTime] = min([Timestamp])
    from    Workflow W
    where   W.[ReportID] = this.[ReportID]
    and W.[User] = this.[User]
    and W.[Timestamp] < this.[EndTime]
    -- First Stop event won't have a previous, so just get the min([Timestamp])
    and (previous.[EndTime] is null or W.[Timestamp] >= previous.[EndTime])
) thisStart
order by this.[User], this.[EndTime]
```